# parseObject.saveInBackground() throw exception

Tags: android, parse-platform, genymotion, back4app

I am new in back{4}app and i tried to use this code:

```
    public void save(View view) {
            ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("users");
            //we will add column
            parseObject.put("name","eyal");
            parseObject.put("age",29);
            parseObject.put("password","123");
            //new thread is open to save the info
            parseObject.saveInBackground();
  }
```

i am getting this exception:

> A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xf6f3046e in tid
>   25170 (ECUTOR-thread-1)

i follow this tutorial:
https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing

Can any one help me?
I try to run by **GenyMotion**, in android studio emulator it is working

Answer (score 0):

```
parseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                Log.e("TAG ", "Success .... ");
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG ", "faillll  ....  " + e.getMessage() + " Code  " + e.getCode());
            }
        }
    });
```

post your error message and error code for getting more information.

Comment: of Course i try that but i cant see any log, and i am sure it is enter this code of course, i think this exception is 'SIGKILL' so we cant catch the exception.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!--This crashes app on Genymotion lollipop emulator when combined with AdView.
It is optional for adView says google docs, ignore the error msg thrown in logcat
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>-->